# Reading XML with different names to Combobox C#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, combobox, dataset

looks like a very simple task by i'm very new to c# and can't seem to find the right answer for this

i have the below xml structure (elements vary in quantity)

```
<config>
<extras>
<dir_update>C:\extension\update.exe</dir_update>
</extras>
<connection_MAIN>
<ip>LOCALHOST,1433</ip>
<bd>DATA</bd>
<user>sa</user>
<password>gzqs=</password>
</connection_MAIN>
<connection_LOBBY>
<ip>10.0.0.2,1433</ip>
<bd>DATA</bd>
<user>sa</user>
<password>I/wqqZIgzqs=</password>
<caixa>5yIz5GPu80s=</caixa>
<printer>cARrmGLQlztLiUDxIJqoPkvJabIiyI9ye4H7t+4muYk=</printer>
</connection_LOBBY>
<connection_FRONT>
<ip>10.0.0.5,1433</ip>
<bd>FIELDS</bd>
<user>sa</user>
<password>I/wqqZIgzqs=</password>
</connection_FRONT>
</config>
```

I'm already getting the elements that start with "connection_" in my combobox and i want the values inside the `<ip>`, `<bd>`, `<user>` and `<password>` when i select the connection on the combobox.

The problem i'm getting is that it's returning the word itself not the value inside on the code below

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                ds.ReadXml(textBox1.Text);
                foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                    if (dt.ToString().Contains("conection_"))
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.ToString().Replace("conection_", ""));
                    }
                }
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                ds.ReadXml(textBox1.Text);
                string v = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
                string ip = ds.Tables[$"conection_{v}"].Columns[0].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Variable ip is getting the value "ip" and i want "LOCALHOST,1433" when i select the first option on my combobox in this example.

Also i want to search for column value by the name ("ip", "bd"), but i seem to only get results when using Columns[0], Columns[1].

I've followed some guides that i've looked around, but they seem to not work on this format of xml or i'm looking at it the wrong way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `DataSet` and `DataTable` data types. The best API to handle XML is *LINQ to XML*.

Check it out below.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string MAIN = "connection_MAIN";
    string IP = string.Empty;
    string bd = string.Empty;
    string user = string.Empty;
    string password = string.Empty;

    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(@"<config>
    <extras>
        <dir_update>C:\extension\update.exe</dir_update>
    </extras>
    <connection_MAIN>
        <ip>LOCALHOST,1433</ip>
        <bd>DATA</bd>
        <user>sa</user>
        <password>gzqs=</password>
    </connection_MAIN>
    <connection_LOBBY>
        <ip>10.0.0.2,1433</ip>
        <bd>DATA</bd>
        <user>sa</user>
        <password>I/wqqZIgzqs=</password>
        <caixa>5yIz5GPu80s=</caixa>
        <printer>cARrmGLQlztLiUDxIJqoPkvJabIiyI9ye4H7t+4muYk=</printer>
    </connection_LOBBY>
    <connection_FRONT>
        <ip>10.0.0.5,1433</ip>
        <bd>FIELDS</bd>
        <user>sa</user>
        <password>I/wqqZIgzqs=</password>
    </connection_FRONT>
</config>");

    // get needed connection fragment
    IEnumerable<XElement> fragment = xml.Descendants(MAIN);

    // get all needed elements one by one
    IP = fragment.Elements("ip")?.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    bd = fragment.Elements("bd")?.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    user = fragment.Elements("user")?.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    password = fragment.Elements("password")?.FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq I put results in to a datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ip", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bd", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("user", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("password", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement connection in doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("connection_")))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    ((string)connection.Name.LocalName).Substring(((string)connection.Name.LocalName).IndexOf("_") + 1),
                    (string)connection.Element("ip"),
                    (string)connection.Element("bd"),
                    (string)connection.Element("user"),
                    (string)connection.Element("password")
                });


            }
            Dictionary<string, DataRow> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            string ip = dict["LOBBY"].Field<string>("ip");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the OP needs to populate combo-boxes with data from XML in the UI layer. Let's wait for the OP response.

Comment: I just put results into a DataTable like the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Nice approach, but how to i get the value from the "connection_LOBBY" element (in my example that would be "10.0.0.2,1433") in a textbox?